# Migrating to OpenId connect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, saml-2.0, openid-connect

I have searched a lot and still confused to get an exact idea so posting here.
I wan to implement SSO in my app. It is Service provider and my identity providers currently supports only WIF and SAML2 implementation for SSO. But in future they also implement OpenIdConnect.

Currently my web application is building in asp.net 4.6 MVC. when my Idp implement openIdconnect I also want to migrate my authentication to openIdConnect.

1. So which will be the best option to implement SSO (WIF or SAML2) now?
2. implementing which of the 2 will be easier to migrate to ODIC in future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for an OWIN-based authentication pipeline. If you chose SAML2 or WS-FED (which I assume is what you mean when you write WIF) doesn't matter. When the Idp supports OpenID Connect you can just remove the SAML2/WS-FED middleware and insert an OpenID Connect middleware instead.

Comment: +1 Just to add that WS-Fed is generally easier to get working so that's my preference. Also these protocols are not mix & match e.g. the claim set from OIDC is not the same as the others and it's a JWT rather than XML token. The middleware takes care of this for you but just to note.